# Xamarin.Forms: Handle Navigation toolbar button (Shell)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to handle any back clicks in my Xamarin.Forms application (android version).

For Android/hardware button was pretty easy, all I had to do was override OnBackButtonPressed method. But this top toolbar is not that easy. I heard that it should work with Shell.SetBackButtonBehavior, but for some reason, it doesn't work for me.

My code is like this, I put it in the page constructor after the InitializeComponents().

```
Shell.SetBackButtonBehavior(this, new BackButtonBehavior {
            Command = new Command(async () =>
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Back","Back","Back")
            )
        });
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The function can be realized by defining **Shell.BackButtonBehavior** in xaml and implementing Command in cs.

Here is a small example of mine:

In xaml：

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding GoBack}" >
    </BackButtonBehavior>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

In cs:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ICommand GoBack { get; set; }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GoBack = new Command(async () =>
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Back", "Back", "Back"));
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I literally copied your code, but it doesnt work. I tried like you did (Xaml + xaml.cs) and also by viewModel (Xaml+VM). But I just cant make it work..

Comment: Make sure this page is not inside the shell.

Comment: UHm, what do you mean "inside the shell"?

Comment: The current page is not in the “ShellContent“ of the Shell.